# Django "Manager isn't accessible via UserProfile instances"

Tags: python, django

Here is my views.py

```
if request.user.is_authenticated():
                changepass = request.user.userprofile.objects.get(user=request.user)
                if changepass.force_password_change == True:
                    changepass.force_password_change = False
                    changepass.save()
                    return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/register/')
                elif changepass.force_password_change == False:
                    return HttpResponseRedirect('/main/')
```

This line `changepass = request.user.userprofile.objects.get(user=request.user)` is the problem according to Django. I am trying to access `force_password_change` from UserProfile.
As the title suggests, I am getting the error `Manager isn't accessible via UserProfile instances`.

Here is my models.py for reference.

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    force_password_change = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)

    post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)
```

Comment: Not relevant to your question, but `if foo.random_boolean_field == True:` is equivalent to `if foo.random_boolean_field:`, which is the preferred expression of this thought in Python. If you ever really need to emphasize that you mean `True` and not "truthy", then you would use `if foo.random_boolean_field is True:`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already have the UserProfile instance when you done `request.user.userprofile`,

at this point, you have a Instance of UserProfile. you can't use the object manager (`.objects`) from that.

you only need

`changepass = request.user.userprofile`

Another way to get the **userprofile object**, is doing

```
UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
```

Comment: I will mark it as right but I don't have enough rep to upvote (lol).

Comment: `request.user.userprofile` is preferable to filtering on the UserProfile objects, if only because it removes a dependency.

Answer (score 3):

You can't access a Manager through a Model instance. In your case, `request.user` is an instance of the `User` class.

To access the manager, you need to use the `UserProfile` class directly.

Although, for what you're trying to accomplish, it's much easier to transverse the database through the request's user object:

```
changepass = request.user.userprofile
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using just

```
changepass = UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
```